# How to add or change data as a string to an imported python file?

Tags: python

**Data to be changed**
*I gave this as an example*

## urlchange.py

```
import requests
Url = ""+".json"
# json request
json_post = request.get(Url).json()

...codes where I pull JSON data
```

## test.py

```
import urlchange
urlchange.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
```

Url= "" <---- how do I change it

I couldn't replace string with an expression

Answer (score 0):

**The code you have written in `urlchange.py` will be executed when you `import` the file so,** ***Change to:***

##### urlchange.py

```
Url=""
def main():
    global Url
    Url += ".json"
    # json request
    json_post = request.get(Url).json()
    # rest of your code
```

##### test.py

```
import urlchange
urlchange.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
url_change.main()
```

### OR

##### urlchange.py

```
def main(Url):
    Url += ".json"
    # json request
    json_post = request.get(Url).json()
    # rest of your code
```

##### test.py

```
import urlchange
Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
url_change.main(Url)
```

Comment: I can't use the data in the json of the site

Comment: Edit your question to add more of your code and elaborate it so it will be reproducible.

Comment: what I want to do is just move the string data but other codes I have defined are causing problems this time

Comment: Check the recent edit.

Comment: name 'Url' is not defined, I am getting an error

Comment: Did you run `test.py` with the first solution or the second? It runs as expected with **no errors**. Edit the question with the error.